# what is target architecture in computer science?

Tags: gcc, architecture, compiler-construction, cpu-architecture

I am a beginner in programming and wanted to download a good C compiler to practice coding. So I thought of GCC and started a small research on it. I read a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_Collection) on it. The article mentioned something about target architecture,which I do not know. Can anyone tell me what it means, and any source I can refer for more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's what you run teh code on......

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The **target architecture** is the architecture which the compiler creates binary files for.

Common architectures are: i386 (Intel 32-bit), x86_64 (Intel 64-bit), armv7, arm64, etc...

GCC compiles C code (after the preprocessing stage) to assembly code,
and the assembly code varies depending on the CPU architecture.
The assembly code is then "assembled" to a binary file.

**Something to keep in mind**:

Two binary files are not guaranteed to be compatible across different operating systems despite sharing the same architecture.

A program compiled on Ubuntu Linux (let's say with arch x86_64) won't work on Windows (with same arc x86_64).

GCC identifies architectures by "triplets", like:

```
x86_64-apple-darwin14.0.0
i386-pc-mingw32
i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

Format is:

```
machine-vendor-operatingsystem (not always followed though)
```

They contain infos on both the architecture and the operating system.